# Problem with data reader

Tags: c#, excel

```
  string Path = TextBox3.Text;
        // initialize the Excel Application class
        Excel.ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
        // create the workbook object by opening the excel file.
        Excel.Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(Path,
                                                     0,
                                                     true,
                                                     5,
                                                     "",
                                                     "",
                                                     true,
                                                     Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
                                                     "\t",
                                                     false,
                                                     false,
                                                     0,
                                                     true,
                                                     1,
                                                     0);
        // get the active worksheet using sheet name or active sheet
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.ActiveSheet;
        int index = 2;
        // This row,column index should be changed as per your need.
        // i.e. which cell in the excel you are interesting to read.
        object rowIndex = (object)index;

        object colIndex1 = 1;
        object colIndex2 = 2;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Examination_Cell;Integrated Security=True");
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
            string x = TextBox1.Text;
            string y = x.Substring(1, 1);
            string z = x.Substring(0, 1);


            TextBox4.Text = ("Roll No. \t Marks\n");
            string RollNo = "";
            string Marks = "";
            while (((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex1]).Value2 != null)
            {

                RollNo = ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex1]).Value2.ToString();
                Marks = ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex2]).Value2.ToString();
                TextBox4.Text += (RollNo + "     \t     " + Marks + "\n");

                index++;
                rowIndex = index;

                sqlCommand.CommandText = "select StudentID from Student where APID=" + int.Parse(y)+ "and Semester=" + int.Parse(z) + "and Roll_No=" + int.Parse(RollNo);
                reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine(reader["Group"]);
                    int a = (int)reader["StudentID"];
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection;
                    cmd2.CommandText = "insert into Result values('" + TextBox1.Text + "'," + int.Parse(TextBox2.Text) + "," + a + "," + RollNo + "," + Marks + ")";
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }
            //Console.ReadLine();



        sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            app.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Here, when I place a breakpoint at "while(reader.Read())", the while loop is entered only once and after that it directly proceeds to "catch" block. The program is actually about fetching data from an excel sheet and StudentID from student table and then insert the data into another table "Result". The data gets fetched from the excel sheet as well as the Student table, but it is not inserted into the Result table. One more thing, I've not given any relationship between Student and Result table. So, is it ok or the relationship needs to be given?
Thanks in advance.........

Comment: Where is Reader.Read?   Change         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); to         Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); it should tell you the line that is failing

Comment: @preet: Post it as an answer.

Comment: @Henk Technically, it's not an answer. :)

Comment: @shivam, can you post real code, with Reader.Read() ?

Comment: I used ex.ToString() and it gave me the following error line:                                                                      Roll No.   Marks
1           10
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at Examination._Default.Method() in C:\Users\Shivam\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Examination\Examination\Default.aspx.cs:line 90

Comment: I hve placed a text box in the design so that I can know whether the excel file is read properly or not. So, in the output only one line is read and after that the error msg gets printed. Please, can anyone help me out?? After coming out once of the while(reader.Read()) loop, it does not enter again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any call to `Reader.Read()` in your code sample.

Also, I would strongly recommend using the best practice for ADO.NET - wrap your connection, command and data readers into `using() { ... }` blocks to automatically free them when no longer needed. Also, you ought to use **parameters** instead of stringing together your SQL select statement.

So your code should be something like:

```
string query = "SELECT StudentID FROM Student WHERE APID = @APID AND Semester  = @Semester AND Roll_No = @RollNo";

using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Examination_Cell;Integrated Security=True"))
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con))
{
   _cmd.Parameters.Add("@APID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ......;
   _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Semester", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ......;
   _cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ......;

   _con.Open();
   using(SqlDataReader reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          // do something
       }
   }

   _con.Close();
}
```